# how to disable a NIC in centos

Tags: networking, centos

I'm looking for a 'one liner' for a script that needs to:

- disable eth0.
- make it not start on boot.
- take away its IP address
- ensure that it does not try to use this address again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One liner? How about this as root?

```
echo "DEVICE=eth0" > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 && service network restart
```

It will remove the configuration for eth0 and replace it with something that is unconfigured.

Comment: +1, beat me to the punch

Comment: what command will cause this file to be used? with out resetting the rest of the interfaces?

Comment: Arthur: You can do `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` instead of `service network restart` to restart eth0 and not all interfaces.

Comment: This command does not bring interface down, but disables it. It is slightly different. Check `ip addr` after `service network restart`, interface is up but no IP (CentOS 7).

Answer (score 10):

In `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` you need to have

```
ONBOOT=no
```

like MDMarra said but you also need to have

```
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

or else the NetworkManager will boot the interface as it ignores the `ONBOOT` setting. Unless you don't use NetworkManager but I think it is common.

Answer (score 4):

In `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` you need to change `ONBOOT=` to `no` and you can delete the lines for `IPADDR` and `NETMASK`.

After you copy the config file, you need to restart the `network` daemon.

Answer (score 2):

No need to restart the network daemon, especially if you have other network cards that are in use. You can just do a 'ifdown eth0'.

Comment: this does not persist on restart with CentOS 7

Answer (score 2):

Put `alias eth0 off` in `/etc/modprobe.conf`. This will make sure that nothing in the system can use it ever. It won't even be able to be brought up manually.

Comment: Thats good and harsh! nothing's coming out of that nic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the correct way is to simply turn it off using the "ONBOOT" directive and to achieve that through a script you can use the following line:

```
sed -i 's/^ONBOOT.*/ONBOOT=no/g' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 && service network restart
```

Answer (score -1):

There is another one option for inexperienced people (like me).
go at www.webmin.com download and install webmin.

configure your server via a web based environment.

Comment: I was looking for a command that i could add to a script.

Answer (score -1):

in case you have not found out yet...
ifconfig  down or up.  The old ifconfig command still allows you to do plumbing /bringing a interface up or down or other options.   Use to be all there was to use when Redhat first came out.

Answer (score -2):

sed -i 's/^ONBOOT.*/ONBOOT=no/g' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno2 && service network restart

## For making it persistent.

chattr +i /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno2